# NHibernate Stale State Issue

Tags: nhibernate

I'm curious if anyone could help me resolve an issue of stale state in nHibernate.

First, the .Net class code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static Test Get(int testId) { return Factory.GetTest(testId); }

    public Test() { Related = new List<TestRelate>(); }

    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TestRelate> Related { get; set; }

    public virtual void Delete() { Factory.Delete(this); }
    public virtual void Save() { Factory.Save(this); }

}
public class TestRelate
{
    protected TestRelate() { }
    public TestRelate(Test test) { TestID = test.ID; }
    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int TestID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual void Delete() { Factory.Delete(this); }
    public virtual void Save() { Factory.Save(this); }
}
class Factory
{
    public static Test GetTest(int testId)
    {
        ISession session = Session.HybridSessionBuilder.Instance;
        IList<Test> ret = null;
        ITransaction tx = null;

        tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        ret = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Test))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("ID", testId))
            .List<Test>();
        tx.Commit();

        return ret.Count == 0 ? null : ret[0];
    }
    public static void Save<T>(T element)
    {
        ISession session = Session.HybridSessionBuilder.Instance;
        ITransaction tx = null;

        tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Save(element);
        tx.Commit();
    }
    public static void Delete<T>(T element)
    {
        ISession session = Session.HybridSessionBuilder.Instance;
        ITransaction tx = null;

        tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Delete(element);
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Then the nHibernate mapping XML:

```
<class name="Data.Test.Test, Data" table="test_info">
  <id name="ID" column="testid">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <bag name="Related" table="test_relate" lazy="false" cascade="none">
    <key column="testid"></key>
    <one-to-many class="Data.Test.TestRelate, Data"></one-to-many>
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Data.Test.TestRelate, Data" table="test_relate">
  <id name="ID" column="relateid">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="TestID" />
  <property name="Data" />
</class>
```

And finally the code I'm having trouble with:

```
Data.Test.Test Test = new Data.Test.Test();
Test.Name = "Hello World";
Test.Save();

Data.Test.TestRelate Relate = new Data.Test.TestRelate(Test);
Relate.Data = "How are you?";
Relate.Save();

Test = Data.Test.Test.Get(Test.ID);
int Count = Test.Related.Count;
```

The problem is that the `Test.Related` list is always empty when I run this code. However if I destroy the NHibernate session and load up the Test again it populates the list as expected. I realize I could probably flush all caching data but it seems like there should be a cleaner solution to this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: where is your SessionFactory, this should be responcible for creating the Sessions

Comment: try session.Flush(); before the commit, the commit should flush any way, but it does not harm to explicitly flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I realized that my approach was due to some past failed attempts at utilizing NHibernate's cascading. I'll go over each one of the issues and what I did to resolve it.

1. If I set up cascading saves NHibernate would fail when I would try to add `Related` elements to a new `Test` element because the `TestID` value is not allowed to be null in the database. Altering the property from an integer type to the `Test` type itself remedied this situation as NHibernate was able to populate the field value after saving the new `Test` element.
2. Attempting to delete a `Related` record by removing it from the list would result in an error due to NHibernate attempting to Update the `TestID` field to null prior to a delete. Adding the `inverse="true"` attribute to the `Bag` mapping element resolved this issue.
3. Deleting the `Test` object would not delete the orphaned `Related` records. Setting the cascade attribute to `all-orphan-delete` remedied this.

Here's all the new code (there were no changes to the Factory class):

```
public class Test
{
    public static Test Get(int testId) { return Factory.GetTest(testId); }

    public Test() { Related = new List<TestRelate>(); }

    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TestRelate> Related { get; set; }

    public virtual void Delete() { Factory.Delete(this); }
    public virtual void Save() { Factory.Save(this); }
}
public class TestRelate
{
    protected TestRelate() { }
    public TestRelate(Test test) { Test = test; }
    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual void Delete() { Factory.Delete(this); }
    public virtual void Save() { Factory.Save(this); }
}
```

Mapping changes:

```
<class name="Data.Test.Test, Data" table="test_info">
  <id name="ID" column="testid">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <bag name="Related" table="test_relate" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
    <key column="testid"></key>
    <one-to-many class="Data.Test.TestRelate, Data"></one-to-many>
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Data.Test.TestRelate, Data" table="test_relate">
  <id name="ID" column="relateid">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="Test" column="testid" />
  <property name="Data" />
</class>
```

The following code now behaves as expected:

```
Data.Test.Test Test; 
Data.Test.TestRelate Relate;

Test = new Data.Test.Test();
Test.Name = "Hello World";
Relate = new Data.Test.TestRelate(Test);
Relate.Data = "How are you?";
Test.Related.Add(Relate);
Test.Save();

Relate = new Data.Test.TestRelate(Test);
Relate.Data = "Relate #2";
Test.Related.Add(Relate);
Test.Save();

Test.Related.RemoveAt(0);
Test.Save();

Test = Data.Test.Test.Get(Test.ID);
int Count = Test.Related.Count;

Test.Delete();
```

I was able to glean most of these answers from http://ayende.com . I highly recommend this site as a resource for nHibernate questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new Data.Test.TestRelate(Test)` there is nothing that adds the new TestRelate instance to the collection in the owner Test. (Unless you do that in the constructor, but I assume you only set TestId there).

You should `Add()` the new TestRelate instance to Test.Related. Nhibernate will notice the change in the collection and save the new item when the session is flushed.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't populate one-to-many collections automatically on commit. You should simply add `TestRelate` instances to the `Related` list, as you would do without NHibernate, and then (if you set a "cascade save" mapping) even commit the `Test` instance only.

There is no need to use the `TestID` property inside the program at all, as this property is actually only a byproduct of relational DB mapping.

Comment: Thanks. You made me re-evaluate why I was going about things that way. Must have been a bad habit I developed when I first started using NHibernate.